# Multiple 'labels' for single checkbox group

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

New to shiny / shinydashboard.

I have a series of options which I would like the user to be able to select one or more of. checkboxGroupInput does the job, but this means that I can only have one label for all of the options. What I would like is to be able to label subsets of my checkboxes, but have the selected options **passed to the server as a single variable**.

For example, suppose I want to show orchestral instruments grouped by type (wind, brass ...);

```
 library(shinydashboard)

    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = 'My Orchestra'),

      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu()
        ),

      dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(
            checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra",
                               label = "String",
                               choices = c("Violin" = "Violin", "Cello" = "Cello"),
                               inline = T
                               ),

            checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra",
                               label = "Woodwind",
                               choices = c("Bassoon" = "Bassoon", "Flute" = "Flute"),
                               inline = T
                               ),

            checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra",
                               label = "Brass",
                               choices = c("Trumpet" = "Trumpet", "Sax" = "Sax"),
                               inline = T
                               )
            ))
        )
   )
```

Regardless of which options are checked, I would like the options to be accessible in server.R as `input$my_orchestra`. As you can see above, I have tried to do this by naming all of the checkboxgroups 'my_orchestra', which does not work. Does anyone have a way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot do what you want they way you want it, as those are unique `divs` and they have to have unique IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe wrap your selections within `reactiveValues` and then use it as `v$my_orchestra` like I did:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'My Orchestra'),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu()
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra1",
                           label = "String",
                           choices = c("Violin" = "Violin", "Cello" = "Cello"),
                           inline = T),

        checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra2",
                           label = "Woodwind",
                           choices = c("Bassoon" = "Bassoon", "Flute" = "Flute"),
                           inline = T),

        checkboxGroupInput("my_orchestra3",
                           label = "Brass",
                           choices = c("Trumpet" = "Trumpet", "Sax" = "Sax"),
                           inline = T)
      ),
      textOutput("Selected")
      )
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    v$my_orchestra <- c(input$my_orchestra1,input$my_orchestra2,input$my_orchestra3)
  })
  output$Selected <- renderText({v$my_orchestra})
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]